# Phonegap and Framework7 build android - Cannot call determinedVisibility()

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I'm trying to build an app with framework7 with phonegap for Android (API 23).

Everything works fine with "phonegap serve" command, and I tested on Phonegap Developer App.

Then I used "phonegap run android"

But I tried on Android Emulator, when I navigated the log windows shows:

"Cannot call determinedVisibility()"

And the $$.ajax() is not working on Android Emulator.

Please help!

Thank you guys!

Comment: This tagged as Phonegap Build but it appears your are not using Build. Please amend the tags to just PhoneGap - you may get answers then.

Comment: thanks for your advice

Comment: No problems. I'll look out for your question in the other section :)

Comment: Do you have idea about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

You need to check for all of your HTML syntax (open/close tag, id duplication...) before building on Android. Because if before script tag there are any syntax error, your code will be terminated right there.

The Intellij Idea IDE will tell you about this syntax problem. So, check your "index.html", *.html files.